# System.Threading.ThreadAbortException (How can we handle this Exception?)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, threadabortexception

```
How can we handle this exception is there some alternative or where i have to make changes?
```

public Form()
        {
            try
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartForm));
                t.Start();
                Thread.Sleep(3200);
                InitializeComponent();
                t.Abort();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        Thread th;

```
    public void StartForm()
    {
        Application.Run(new Form3());
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        th = new Thread(opennewform);
        th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        th.Start();
    }
    private void opennewform(object obj)
    {
        Application.Run(new Form2());

    }
```

[This is the Screen Shoot of this Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaJfo.png)

Comment: [`Thread.Abort()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b50fdsz(v=vs.110).aspx) invokes a `ThreadAbortException` on the thread. You didn't catch any exceptions (I don't see the code of Form3) in your thread. Add a try...catch to `StartForm()` and you'll be able to handle this exception.

Comment: You are using *very* bad practices that you'll end up regretting deeply.  Lucky to discover problems this early.  The dispatcher loop that is started by Application.Run() has a back-stop for *any* unhandled exception, it raises the Application.ThreadException event.  That is the mild problem, much more severe is the SystemEvents class.  Used by lots of controls in the toolbox.  Inevitably, some of your form object are going to get this event on the wrong thread.  Very apt to cause deadlock.  Never, *never* do this.

Comment: Please take care of the formatting. This is so hard to read...